# Responsive Chip - Materialize.css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I’m adding first name and last name inside a chip as below.

```
<div class="chip">{{firstName}}  {{lastName}}</div>
```

When the length of name is long, it is coming out the chip. I want to make the chip responsive so that the name fits into it. Please guide how to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipses;
```